# The Code is not going as i expected , i wanted if there is wrong input it will say wrong , and if the input is right it will say Yes

Tags: python, input, passwords

**If the password input is right it will print('OKAY') , and if the input is wrong it will say print('wrong password')**

```
name=input("Enter your name: ")
print("Hello, " + name)


LEGAL_AGE=18
 age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))

 if age<18 :
    print("GO HOME")
 else:

    password =input("TYPE YOUR PASSWORD : ")


    if password==int(12345):
       print('YES , YOU CAN ENTER NOW')
 else:
    print('WRONG')
```

Comment: You converted `12345` to `int` (it is already an `int`) instead of `password`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this for it to work -

```
name=input("Enter your name: ")
print("Hello, " + name)


LEGAL_AGE=18
age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))

if age<18 :
    print("GO HOME")
    
else:
    password =input("TYPE YOUR PASSWORD : ")
    
    if int(password)==12345:
       print('YES , YOU CAN ENTER NOW')
    else:
        print('WRONG')
```

In your code, you are converting an already integer to int in the statement `int(12345)` which essentially doesn't have any effect. You need to convert the password to integer which is read by python as a string.

Do note that you are not required to convert the password to an integer, you can check it against a string as well like -

```
name=input("Enter your name: ")
print("Hello, " + name)


LEGAL_AGE=18
age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))

if age<18 :
    print("GO HOME")
    
else:
    password =input("TYPE YOUR PASSWORD : ")
    
    if password=='12345':
       print('YES , YOU CAN ENTER NOW')
    else:
        print('WRONG')
```

Both the above methods are correct.

Comment: thankx a lot bro , you are great !!!!!!!

Comment: @MDZIAURRAHMAN  glad to help. You may upvote/mark it as accepted if it helped